What is a Word for the Repetition of a Theme Song throughout a Show
What is a word to describe the theme song of a show, such as a movie or cartoon, in which it recurs often, but in a toned-down mode such as played softly by a single horn or string instrument. The replays seem to only occur during pivotal parts of the show. The replay is much shorter and only last a few bars of the main chorus, the intro, or outro of the theme song.
This replay of the theme is not bound to the entrance of a specific character or characters, it is more closely associated with plot twists.

You mean literally playing continuously throughout the show? Or the same tune occurring at different moments through the film - the Wikipedia article on film scores discusses techniques such as the repetition of themes and motifs. But having the same music play all the time is more common in video games than films or TV shows. This might be better on a music forum or Music SE though.

@StuartF - Thanks for the input.

This question is similar to: sound played when a key character appears. [leitmotif:
A recurrent theme throughout a musical or literary composition, associated with a particular person, idea, or situation.] + [motif]. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@EdwinAshworth - The question was updated to emphasize that the replay is not bound to characters.

@StuartF - " Or the same tune occurring at different moments through the film" <--this one.

The answer contains 'a musical or literary composition, associated with a particular person, idea, or situation. This answers  the question. The answers here are repeats.

I really don't think you mean. "continues to play throughout." That would be ostinato. I suspect you mean "recurs often." It might be that the most relevant term is simply "reprise."

@AndyBonner - Noted and updated, thank you.

signature tune is usually used at the beginning or at the end of a TV programme,, but I believe it may also  be associated to pivotal moments.

A repeated element in narrative and music is called a "motif"
Motif (narrative)

any distinctive feature or idea that recurs across a story;

Motif (music)

a short musical idea, a salient recurring figure, musical fragment or succession of notes that has some special importance in or is characteristic of a composition

Leitmotif

a "short, recurring musical phrase" associated with a particular person, place, or idea


I think Leitmotif is the closest. I know the same music would play in situations such as when an evil plot was foiled by the good guys, and while they were reflecting on their actions.

@RossBush leitmotif is not just for music.

I think the term is “leitmotif.” That is if you mean a recurring musical theme associated with a particular character, place, idea, or emotion..
